# How would I order by multiple fields in CosmosDB and still use CosmosDB's pagination in one query?

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb

Say I have a collection with documents like this:

```
{
     "ClientName": "7-Eleven",
     "OtherName": "Other",
     "Cost": "1200"
}
```

I would like to query it to order by Cost descending then ClientName and then OtherName. The query language doesn't seem to support ordering by more than one field. I'm afraid that what I'm asking is impossible without doing multiple separate queries or without writing a stored procedure. If that's the case, how would you do this using a manner other than one query?

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible to ORDER BY on several fields on CosmosDB by manually building the SQL statements. [Here is the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-ca/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy) to the Microsoft doc for composite indexes.

Also, to have the opportunity to do everything in LINQ, go vote for [this idea](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/38380204-add-support-for-thenby-thenbydescending-when-order) on the Azure Feedback Forum.

**edit**

With the new [CosmosV3 nuget](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3), it's now possible to order by more than 1 field. Simply use the ThenBy or ThenByDescending after your OrderBy method and it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, at time of writing (13 May, 2018), the SQL API only supports a single field in `order by` clauses.  The SQL Query language itself has support for ordering by multiple fields.  That is shown below and you can read more in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-reference#bk_orderby_clause).

```
ORDER BY <sort_specification>  
<sort_specification> ::= <sort_expression> [, <sort_expression>]  
<sort_expression> ::= <scalar_expression> [ASC | DESC]
```

However, the docs go on to say that only a single field is supported by CosmosDB at this time:

> While the query grammar supports multiple order by properties, the Azure Cosmos DB query runtime supports sorting only against a single property, and only against property names, i.e., not against computed properties.

The good news, however, is that it seems that [work is underway](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/16883608-allow-multi-order-by) to support multiple sort fields.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing all the sorting I needed to on these fields before inserting into CosmosDB. I added a field called "SortOrder" that I then went and used in the OrderBy. It was nice because I was able to keep all the business logic in the business layer this way.